# Google App Engine Flask Sample ERROR: "no module named six"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python, six

after installing the gcloud SDK and cloning the samples git rep to my local machine, I opened the **Flask / hello_world** sample and did `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`. I am using virtualenv.

Then I got the following error:

```
File "/Users/assafshamia/Freebird/Techradar/dev/samples/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/py27compat.py", line 7, in <module>
        import six
    ImportError: No module named six
```

I then did  `pip install -t lib six`, which did install six under /lib, but I still get the above error.

any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `-t` flag? If you activated your virtualenv, let pip install packages in it (omit `-t lib` part).

Comment: because the app engine SDK will look for 3rd party modules under /lib. in that sample code there is a special file called appengine_config.py with the line vendor.add('lib').

Comment: Ah, alright, I see...

Comment: in any case, removing -t lib still gives an error "no module named six". it is when it tries to install itsdangerous.

Comment: Just to check, you are using Homebrew Python version?

Comment: @NightOwl were u able fix this issue. Facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known bug https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1042.

adding "six" to requirements.txt did the trick.